# dashdb out of memory on Cloudant sync

Tags: cloudant, dashdb

I got the following error trying to warehouse a 7.7Gb database from Cloudant. How can I resolve this?

```
Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest:195'
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:195)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1274)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
... 1 more
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

where do you see this error? are you triggering some api to call warehouse creation in cloudant ?

Can you check if there is a _warehouser database created on the cloudant side and check if there is error in the doc reported if the transformation failed?

the other thing we can check try is increasing the java memory "-Xmx2048M -Xms512M " ?